# Meteor dynamic form fields generation

Tags: meteor

I am building a testing app where admin can build up questions for each test, each test will have its own set of fields (text, drop down, checkboxes, radio...etc), so I was wondering if there is any Meteor package that can help me with the dynamic form generation?

I've checked aldeed: autoform but as far as I understood all form fields (schema) must be defined statically, while in my case it is dynamically generated, saved/ retrieved in/ from the tests collection, where I save each test along with its fields (label, type, min, max...etc). Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Autoform](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform) could automatically create your form based on a schema as it uses [simple schema](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema) (or alternatively [collection2](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-collection2)). You could store and update your schema in the DB serialized for example and then use it with `parseJSON`.

```
var schema = $.parseJSON(jsonFromDB);
CollectionSchema = new SimpleSchema(schema);

{{> quickForm schema=CollectionSchema}}
```

Not tested but I think it should work.